# General error: 1005 Can't create table 'magento2.easylife_table' in magento

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have creating a table through my package(Ics->easylife->sql->install-0.0.1.php) file, but it's returning error.

can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

my code is

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();


$table = $installer->getConnection()

->newTable($installer->getTable('easylife/easylife_table'))

->addColumn('easylife_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
    ), 'EasyLife ID')

->addColumn('nom', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array( ), 'Number')

->addColumn('prenom', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array( ), 'Pre Number')

->addColumn('telephone', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '64k', array( ), 'Telephone Number')

->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('easylife/easylife_table', 'easylife_id', 'easylife/easylife_table', 'easylife_id'),
        'easylife_id', $installer->getTable('easylife/easylife_table'), 'easylife_id',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)

->setComment('Easy Life Table');

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it's the foreign key you are trying to add.
From what I see, you try to add a foreign key to the same field in the same table. That won'y work.
Either drop the `addForeignKey` or reference an other table.

Comment: hi mari, you mean >addColumn('easylife_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
    ), 'EasyLife ID') this will be a foreignkey?

Comment: @ManojKumar. No. I mean `->addForeignKey(....)`. And the name is Marius. Not Mari.

Comment: hi marius, it's k I understand, if I want to add another table foreignkey then I will use addForeignKey(..) method I'm right? for this table addColumn('easylife_id'..) is primary key right?

Comment: That's the primary key.